# Add Attachment and Cc Parameter to smtp Email function

Tags: powershell, sendmail

My powershell script currently handles sending an email from the command line to a list of users. I would like to add an attachment to the email and also a list of Cc so all emails don't come through the "To" email parameter. Here is my current function.

```
function SendEmail
{  
$smtpServer = "smtp.server"
$smtpFrom = "PROD <email@gmail.com>" 
$smtpTo = "me@gmail.com"  
$messageSubject = "Weekly List "+$day
$messagebody = "Hi User, Please find attached document. Thank you."

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($smtpFrom,$smtpTo,$messageSubject,$messagebody)
}
```

My attempt was to add a variable called $attachment = "\PathtoFile" 
and add $attachment into the Send function, but that didn't work...

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet?

Comment: I was having issues in adding the date variable to the subject and also special characters to the body of the email such as " ' " when I used the Send-mailmessage cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Send-MailMessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) with the `Attachments` and `Cc` parameter:

```
Send-MailMessage -Attachments "C:\path\to\attachment.ext" -Cc "myboss@gmail.com"
```

You can also specify an encoding (you mentioned special characters):

```
Send-MailMessage -Encoding UTF8
```

In general, I would recommend [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) the parameters, so it ends up looking like this:

```
$MyAttachments = ".\a\relative\path.ext","C:\another\file.ext"

$MailParams  = @{
    SmtpServer = "smtp.server"
    From = "PROD <email@gmail.com>" 
    To = "me@gmail.com"  
    Subject = "Weekly List "+$day
    Body = "Hi User, Please find attached document. Thank you."
    Attachments = $MyAttachments
    Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
}

Send-MailMessage @MailParams
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias. That worked great! One last question, does the Cc parameter not take multiple emails? I added two emails separated by comma, and it only emailed the second user.

Comment: `Cc` accepts multiple addresses, sure you spelled the email adress correctly?